# Edit review ban for approving code formatting ... why?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, review-suspension

I know, my EDIT history wasn't exactly great; so I tried to improve on that ... but still, I ran into this [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14147467)

Back then, I edited the suggestion (I think I removed that "Thank you" line that the person suggesting the edit put in).

And then *Community* approved as well; and now, two weeks later I am told about being banned because of that edit. So, probably I did something wrong again; but I am wondering: what exactly?

Comment: That's probably because you did not correct the code snippet which included the text "for example:, original tweet, tweet after collection" and you approved an edit which did not make any significant corrections whatsoever, replaced the fluff with a fluffy "Thank you" note.

Comment: But that alone doesn't seem to warrant a suspension. Perhaps you had some more severely flawed reviews before that?

Comment: Probably I violated my conditions of probation.

Comment: The addition of code formatting is wrong in all three instances, and the code block is also not correctly used (as @NSNoob) explained. Perhaps you mistakenly think that code formatting may be used for emphasis?

Comment: Also there are some grammatical errors as well which were retained (I have corrected them now)

Comment: @GhostCat i don't know why people are not thinking about area of expertise first before editing some one reply. in my opinion, if you are subject matter expert for the question then only you are allowed to edit and reply for the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That edit doesn't do *anything at all* to improve the post. The signature line is just replaced, not deleted (as it should be), `random` terms are decorated with code `formatting` and the existing code formatting for the sample isn't edited out. This is a bad edit *by all means possible* and should never been approved/improved. Oh, did I mention that 'Twiter' should be spelt as 'Twitter' and that the title can use some editing as well?

You have been banned manually by a ♦ moderator, but, if this is for this review alone or not, mere mortals like me cannot know, and we need to wait for the ♦ moderator to explain.

> And then Community approved as well

This is always the case when you <kbd>Improve & Edit</kbd> from the review queue.