# I approved an edit adding backticks and fixing a typo - was that so bad as to deserve a review ban?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-suspension, specific-edit

I just discovered that I was banned from reviewing for approving [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100425). At least, the "Review" page shows so:

[image]

I just don't understand, what was wrong with it? There were two changes in formatting and one typo fix. This seems appropriate to me.

- The name of the file "test.html" was changed in two places to include code formatting, so that it stood out like `test.html`.
- The misspelled word "knwo" was corrected to "know".

I also don't understand why I was banned from *all* review queues? Why not just from "Suggested Edits" queue?

**Added:**
I *do* understand that edits with formatting only, or inappropriate formatting, is frowned upon and I do reject such suggestions, but this particular edit was also fixing a typo which clearly was an *improvement*.

Comment: The edit is a bit minor but I might also have approved it.

Comment: I think mods don't like editors to get rep just for editing formatting. Editing formatting is for 2k+ rep. You've been manually banned for approving (and encouraging) that.

Comment: I personally would have rejected this, as it's such a minimal improvement on a two year old question, it doesn't warrant bumping to the front page. However, a review ban certainly shouldn't be issued as a result of this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If there was _only_ (minor) formatting, I'd reject it, but there also was typo fix. That means that the person clearly read the text and tried to improve it. Now, this edit is rejected by moderator, that means there is "knwo" again. Is it really better alternative for +2 rep?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, this dupe also doesn't answer my question. Fixing "knwo -> know" is clearly _improvement_, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: the moderator judgement prevails here. It was considered minor. Or maybe the mod didn't even see the typo on "know". Who knwos?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre _the moderator judgement prevails here_, I'd like to know this judgement, rather than see just the link to suggested edit and trying to understand what exactly was wrong.

Comment: The only useful part of the edit was the typo fix. The other part, highlighting file names in code blocks, was unnecessary and useless. I would have “reject and edit” to just fix the typo.

Comment: @Moritz Yes, perhaps I should have "reject&edit" it, though every time I do that I feel like I'm steeling their work...

Comment: @Moritz: I suspect that those backticks were only used to get to the minimum change count.

Comment: It was in response to a flag - there was a reviewer basically adding backticks https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579443/acesaif?tab=activity. Yes reject and edit the typo. In cases of a post that's really old, it's preferable not to bump it for the sake of one char. The duplicate targets here answer your question perfectly. Note I will only ever go through review histories in response to flags.

Comment: Bumping to the front page is not an issue for Stack Overflow (in contrast to all other Stack Exchange sites). The rate of new questions is way too high for that - about one every 47 seconds right now (77 questions per hour - extrapolated 1800 per day, but I think right now is low traffic time).

Comment: @PeterMortensen we're hard pushed getting low quality stuff off the site, to float the good stuff on the front page, let alone needlessly adding old posts to the front page (one of the posts was ten years old). As a general rule of thumb it's a good policy to try and enforce, otherwise we can have editors going bananas on editing sprees and then it really does flood the front page. The thin edge of the wedge - where to stop it.

Comment: I may be a bit strict, but code formatting is for code. Adding backticks for non-code stuff such as file names is a bad edit, and probably just noise added on purpose to be able to make a one-character edit. Edits like that should always be rejected imo.

Comment: *though every time I do that I feel like I'm steeling their work.* If it helps, it's not like you're putting your name on an original idea or anything like that. You're fixing a typo. You're not stealing their work, you're letting them know that the edit they made has problems. And we need editors to know what a good edit is and isn't before they hit 2K and stop having their edits reviewed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth filenames should be backticked whenever they have spaces or dots or other typographic elements that conflict with written English.

Comment: @Cœur Agree to disagree on that. I generally italicize filenames to indicate they're not code, but not English either, but that's just preference. I don't think we should use code formatting for non-code, even if it's a filename, error or output. You can use blockquotes, italics and boldfacing to format that appropriately.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth OK, there may be alternatives to backticks. Maybe worth to have a separate question on that regarding which delimiter is the best for filenames, as "___no delimiter/formatting___" doesn't fit in English.

Comment: I would have reject and edited this if I knew the backstory of the editor adding backticks to lots of posts... which I would've only known if I were responding to the flag as a moderator. If I came across this as a normal user/reviewer I would have just Edited (aka Approve and Edit) to remove the backticks from the file. Either way, I think a ban is unnecessary. Was the ban caused by the moderator action? If not, then the ban is just an unfortunately circumstance of you having too many failed suggested edit review audits recently.

Comment: @TylerH it was caused by a moderator action, then undone as a consequence of this meta question: see Yvette's answer.

Comment: I would guess that the formatting was done in order to get around the character limit for suggested edits.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think it's an interesting question whether filenames should be inline code blocks or not. The Stack Overflow [markdown guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) don't say anything about it; I personally use inline code markup for filenames, but if you look at O'Reilly books, they use italics for filenames.

Comment: Easy: code blocks (“backticks”) are for code, and file names are not code. :)

Comment: If on one hand there's a push for clarity and readability - and edits form a large part of that, even if they just backtick or spellcheck - but the issue is with post bumping, why are we not introducing a "minor edit" feature which wouldn't cause the bump? Give reviewers the ability to approve but mark as minor, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was in response to a flag - there was an [editor basically adding backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579443/acesaif?tab=activity). Yes ***reject and edit*** the typo. In cases of a post that's really old, it's preferable not to bump it for the sake of one char.

The purpose of the review ban is to make the reviewer take note. I need to customise my ban messages to explain why there is a ban. Linking to a post like this may be a good idea. Sorry there wasn't enough explanation.

Note I will only ever go through review histories in response to flags.

If people feel the need to polish posts, at least wait until you have edit privileges. By then you should have a feel of what is ok and what is not. The review system is designed to teach people the best way to go about things.

As for review banning only certain queues we have no control over that. It's an all or nothing approach.

I've removed the review ban, as it's really about gaining the person's attention so they can learn from it and you've certainly done that.

See also:

- [Edit review ban for approving code formatting ... why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338035/edit-review-ban-for-approving-code-formatting-why)
- [Banned from reviewing for approving an approved edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336405/banned-from-reviewing-for-approving-an-approved-edit)
- [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

  > Keep in mind that if you have less than 2,000 rep, all of your edits need to be approved in the suggested edit review queue. Don't waste reviewers' time by searching for and correcting simple errors en masse.
  >
  > Also, editing a post bumps it to the front page, so don't edit too many posts in quick succession.

Comment: and noone believed me when I marked the question as duplicate...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if people want to split hairs and say - well there was also a typo, let them. It's not important either way. I suppose it gets another answer on the board. As long as all the similar/duplicated posts are linked. :)

Comment: can we keep that one as a canonical dupe for the future same questions ? :) so next time you (and other mods) have more time to attend to more serious matters on the site, like obscenity, voting fraud, spam? Good answer BTW

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you mean keep this post as a canonical?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this person indeed suggested a couple of "add backticks" edits, though you have to admit, some of them did improve those questions. Anyway, I understand the reason now. Polishing posts is for 2k+ reps users, and only significant edits/improvements until that. The question about banning _all_ queues still stands, but I reckon there is no technical ability to ban queues selectively.

Comment: @Styx oh yes. I'll edit to add that. We don't have any control about which queues, it's an all or nothing, I'll lift the ban now anyway. It's about learning not punishment. You've certainly paid attention and I appreciate that.

Comment: I'll keep it as my personal reference anyway

Comment: There may be other reasons for avoiding one-character edits (comprehensive edits being one of them), but [bumping is not one of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379754/i-approved-an-edit-adding-backticks-and-fixing-a-typo-was-that-so-bad-as-to-de?cb=1#comment667364_379754) (on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Peter I disagree. A bunch of noisy edits can (and does) still launch a DoS on [the "interesting" questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting), which is what I primarily use to find, um, interesting questions to answer. I'm not saying to avoid editing, of course. I'm just saying you still have to strike a balance, even on a very large site. I mostly see this problem with tag "burnination" sprees, though, rather than earnest attempts to clean up formatting/grammar.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks, I appreciate that, though I have to admin that my goal was not to understand the reason of ban, but to understand what was wrong with this edit. I did understand, yes. I also didn't know that edits of old posts bump them to the front page, so I will be more careful from now on.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this - I received a ban regarding for accepting one of this user's edits, and while I was able to work out for myself that I'd approved an edit that was too trivial, I agree it would have been helpful to get some kind of informative message as to why the ban was issued (though I appreciate you may not have much time).  Thanks again for the work that you do, and thanks to Samuel Liew for pointing me towards this post.

Comment: Bah, ban me for review too, as [I did approve a minor typo correction too](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21927845)! I'm siding with Styx here: we shouldn't barrage editors from improving posts, even for minor edits. If the problem comes from too many suggested edits, then act on the editor, not on the reviewers!

Comment: Yvette, you're suggesting **_reject and edit_**, but all you did was rejecting without performing the _edit_ part. So I've done it for you and I've fixed the typo from the linked post.

Comment: What more could have been improved on the post that the editor missed? (Might be a grammar problem in the answer, I'm not sure, I'm not really an expert in HTML). Every meta topic I've found on the topic has said that "too minor isn't a reject reason", and that any edit, no matter how small, if it improves something, is worth doing (as long as it fixes all issues on the post); did this change?

Comment: This should really be it's own Meta Question ... but ... If the problem is that the edit will cause the post to get bumped, then isn't a "better" solution to make a way to approve edits without bumping the post? i.e. It shouldn't be "don't approve minor edits" but rather "don't bump minor edits"?

Comment: If that's the case, how exactly should I go about notifying high rep users of problems? Should I make some giant gist and post that somewhere? I end up on the dustiest possible corners of SO [(i.e., the kind of hard questions SO wants sometimes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4975230)) and I've seen many old posts with problems, no high rep users are going to see those. Whatever the content improvement plan is for SO, from what I've seen it's not working, outside of high traffic posts things can get pretty messy.

Comment: @jrh You can ask on meta, or in a chatroom, or earn enough rep to make edits that don't need to be approved, or continue making edits that primarily fix stuff in a post

Comment: I'm really busy today, but I will get back to all this in the next 12 -24 hours.

Comment: It would be more appropriate not to bump old questions when there is only a small change was made. Both editor and reviewers completed their job. The fact that the question is old is not their problem.

Comment: @gudok it ***is*** the responsibility of editors and reviewers to make a note of how old a post is.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It is currently the responsibility of editors and reviewers to make a note of how old a post is, because the system erroneously bumps minor edits. If the system worked correctly, and didn't bump minor edits, then there would be no problem with approving minor edits, right?

Comment: @YvetteColomb if SO is a knowledge repository,does the age of a post really matter though, if it's still useful? Isn't it more important to maintain all the hard work people put in over the years than it is to clutter the front page for a couple of seconds? (Though I'd rather posts not get bumped automatically at all for edits in most cases, I'd rather err on the side of "let's fix content" than "let's not distract answerers for a couple seconds")

Comment: @YvetteColomb I hope I didn't come across too harshly. I'm curious and have a desire to improve things, rather than being angry. As you often point out it's hard to convey things well in comments, so I've created a question which I hope better states my position: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379824/should-minor-edits-cause-a-post-to-be-bumped The previous questions on the topic got buried or ignored, so hopefully this one will get some better quality responses.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Can you clarify what you mean by your last comment? IMO questions with problems should be edited no matter their age. We do ask some discretion from low-rep users who can only make suggestions so as to avoid piling on less-important tasks for edit reviewers... but that's a matter of politeness; it's certainly not something that should earn a Reject action IMO.

Comment: @TylerH I would've rejected this, no improvement, the filenames without the code formatting are easier to read IMO, although I agree with the sentiment in general

Comment: Bumping is not a good reason to refrain from fixing actual problems. SO needs to fix this, like we've been saying since before I even became a member. If we don't want minor edits to bump a post, that should be implemented in the site software, not used as an excuse to leave the site worse off than it could be.

Comment: I agree with gudok and jpmc26 that we should fix the bumping logic instead of working around it by not editing old questions.

Comment: What a poor logic "question is old, edit is minor, reject it and don't bump the question". If edit is good, it must be approved.

Answer (score 17):

For what it's worth, I think you did the right thing on this post and that Yvette shouldn't have rolled back this particular edit.

What complicates things is that most of this editor's *other* suggestions this day are either outright objectively bad or at least contain some objectively bad changes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22066690 makes the last sentence of the post ungrammatical and nonsensical
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100450 backticks technology names that definitely aren't being used as identifiers in code; this isn't appropriate
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100527 again wrongly backticks a technology name ('`Flask`')
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100935 makes the grammar worse and makes the file path in the inline code span further deviate from the one included in the code block (which has a capital `P` in `/Possible/`)

However, [the edit that this Meta question is about](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100425) is, to my eyes, entirely good and deserving of approval. It fixes an outright typo, which is definitely good. It also adds backticks around the filename `test.html`, which would be subjective and a matter of taste normally... except that the post being edited already uses backticks around `test.html` in the *other* place where the name is used. Making the formatting of the post internally consistent strikes me as good, even if neither of the two styles is clearly better than the other.

For (I presume) that reason or a similar one, Cœur has rolled back Yvette's rollback. I think that's the correct outcome.

In general, editors on backticking sprees will tend to make *some* good edits; *some* of the backticks they add are probably appropriate, they may be fixing typos as well, and if you're lucky that results in at least a few clearly positive edits getting made even if the majority of the changes made in the spree are bad. It doesn't make sense to do a mass rollback and review ban without considering the virtues of the individual edits, but that looks to me like what Yvette did here.

On the other hand, you did, uh, approve [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22100450) by the same editor which did nothing but add backticks, most of which were around technology names in a context where they were simply being used as proper nouns in prose, not as code or identifiers of any kind. That's definitely a wrong review on your part, and I'd have no issue with Yvette sending a raised eyebrow your way over *that* approval.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and you're right about "_this edit_", I shouldn't have approved it also. It seems I was too careless this day, and if my ban banner would have link to _this_ edit, I wouldn't even wonder about the reason.